# Crashlytics.logException method throwing illegal state exception. Not able to collect non-fatal issues for some activities

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

My app uses the above Firebase Crashlytics feature but I am running into a strange problem. Recently I saw in my app's playstore crashes, an exception (see attached photo).
[image: Crash Description]
 The corresponding code in that location is as follows:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_sites)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))

        init()
        try{
            loadSitesSetAdapter()
        } catch (e:NullPointerException){
            Crashlytics.logException(e) // this is line 55 as crash
            finish()
//            startActivity(Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java))
        }
```

The Fabric initialisation is as follows in my app:

in app level gradle I have:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
}
```

In main activity I have the following:

```
val crashlyticsKit = Crashlytics.Builder()
                                    .core(CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
                                    .build();

    // Initialize Fabric with the debug-disabled crashlytics.
    Fabric.with(this,crashlyticsKit)
```

and last but not the least my dependency in gradle file is as follows:

```
// Crashlytics
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Is there something obvious I am missing here? Help please

Answer (score 2):

Fabric has to be initialized before it can be used in an app. Where you are calling `Crashlytics.logException(e)`, is that done before the line `Fabric.with(this,crashlyticsKit)`? If not then, you have to initialize Fabric before you can use any of its methods.

If you're going to be calling Fabric methods in multiple activities/screens, then it's best to have an Application subclass where you can initialize Fabric.

See the getting started paragraph here:
https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/overview.html#manual-setup

Comment: Thanks.  I am doing that in the main activity only. I didn’t knew it needs to be done for every activity.

Comment: Yes if you want to use it in multiple activites just make an Application subclass and initialize it in that class's onCreate method.

Comment: This is where it gets confusing: I was checking this page : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#android at point2 it says 'in any one of your activities'

Comment: If you ONLY want it to be used in one activity, it's fine. But for multiple screens you should put it in an Application subclass. If not, then you'll just have to put it in onCreate for each Activity you want to use it in.